# Port Forward :80 and :8080 to Two Different Servers

Tags: centos, iptables, rhel, port-forwarding

On a CentOS 6 server with an IP address of 172.16.1.10, how can I configure iptables to route traffic destined for 172.16.1.10:80 to 192.168.1.10:80, and traffic destined for 172.16.1.10:8080 to 192.168.1.11:8080?  Traffic comes in on eth0 and must leave on eth1.  Thanks!

Comment: You find documentation that explains how to do it for one port, then you repeat that for another port.  What have you tried and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you are talking about http traffic (I'm assuming that from the ports given), [proxying](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) might be preferable to using (D)NAT.

IPTables wise this should do it:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 172.16.1.10 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.10:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 172.16.1.10 --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.10:8080
```

possibly related: https://serverfault.com/questions/179200/difference-beetween-dnat-and-redirect-in-iptables

Comment: What about Server-side configuration? e.g. `VirtualHost` directive with `apache`.